# OAuth bearer token rejected by Google Cloud REST API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

As per google's docs, I'm generating my oauth access token like this:

```
export TOKEN=$(~/go/bin/oauth2l fetch -jwt -json ~/.google/my-service-key.json cloud-platform)
```

I'm then doing requests to Google's REST API like this:

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d (...) $URL
```

The response I'm getting back from Google is that I'm not providing an OAuth token, when I clearly am:

```
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

Other posts suggest to use `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token` instead of the OAuth token, but I know this to be the incorrect approach, as Google's API responds back that it wants a service account OAuth token and not an identity.

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: There are two types of access tokens. Signed JWT and Google OAuth 2 Access Token. You exchange the Signed JWT for a Google Access Token. Some Google services accept the first, most require the second. I don't use the `oath2l` program but I guess you are generating a Signed JWT.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an old (bad) token gets cached from before you rotated the `service_account.json`.

### Delete Cache

Try this:

```sh
rm ~/.oauth2l
```

### Token vs JWT

And try getting an API token before you sign the JWT:

```sh
oauth2l fetch cloud-platform
```

### Scope vs Audience

Also, the API token requires a `scope` (shown above), whereas the JWT requires an audience `aud`, which is a URL:

```sh
oauth2l fetch --jwt https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
```

### ENVs

You may also want to make sure that you don't have competing configuration, see if `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is set.

```sh
echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
unset GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Or potentially use it instead of `--json ./service_account.json`:

```sh
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=$HOME/.config/google/service_account.json
```

HTH